# Can I change server collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud SQL instance with a default server collation of `utf8_general_ci`.  I'd like to change this to `utf8_unicode_ci`.  How can I do this?

Before, I could go to the "old" Google Cloud SQL console and run SQL as a super-admin; I thought I could make the change this way.  However, I don't see this link anywhere in the new console, and when running SQL remotely (even as root), I cannot perform super-admin changes.

I've also looked at [configuring MySQL flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags), but only the character set is available for modification (`character_set_server`), not the collation.

Is there a way I can change the default server collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` in a Google Cloud SQL instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to do this currently.

The other answer demonstrates how to edit the collation for specific databases, not server-wide.  The Google Cloud SQL API does not seem to have a method for doing this server- or instance-wide.

Comment: you can submit this as a feature request on the Cloud SQL public issue tracker:  https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list

Answer (score 3):

Use [Google Cloud SQL API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/databases?hl=en) to change the collation value of your GCS databases. In this case, use [`patch`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/databases/patch) method as you want to do a partial update of the databases settings. You can do this through APIs Explorer [`Try it!`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/databases/patch#try-it).

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Is there a way to do this instance-wide?  Or just for individual databases?  Unfortunately, doing it for individual DBs does not solve the collation problem I'm having.